# Launching an HTML/Javascript Adobe Air application from a local HTML file.

Tags: javascript, html, air

I am creating my first HTML based Adobe Air application and need it to launch from a webpage on load. I've set allowBrowserInvocation to true but every example I see is from a flash based Air application. If anyone can provide me with a very simple html page that has javascript to call a HTML based Air application that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is, it can't be done.

As far as I'm aware launching Air applications from the browser is done via undocumented AS3 classes such as `ProductManager` and `Air Browser API`. I know that the `Air Browser API` relies on an external SWF and hence, I don't think you can interact with it using javascript (unless you can find some way of extending the SWF and using `ExternalInterface` to register a callback?)

The fact they are undocumented means there isn't much resource out there. But there is still some:

[Installing and running an AIR applications from a web page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html)

[Example usage of ProductManager](http://blog.everythingflex.com/2009/06/08/open-an-air-application-from-a-2nd-air-application/)